# How i align three elements with bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Before I upgrade to bootstrap 4 I was doing this :

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              My bloc 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              My bloc 2
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              My bloc 3
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And in Bootstrap 3 with the content of bloc 1 more important than bloc 2 and 3 it's look like :
[image]

But with Bootstrap 4 it's look like this :
[image]

How can I make this work in Bootstrap 4. I can't find a solution on Bootstrap 4 docs (or I'm blind).
Please don't answer me with CSS like (this don't work just an example):

```
#bloc2{
    display: block;
}
```

Or something like this, it's an example and I have similar case with different bloc in another page.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to use the class `container` in a `<div>` which brings together the 3 `row`.

Comment: @FoxCy I do it, just simplify my code here, will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @FoxCy help me with this.

The answer was :

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
               My bloc 1
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="row">My bloc 2</div>
              <div class="row">My bloc 3</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align the 3 elements you have to never surpassed the 12 columns for each `row`.

 Try this please :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            My block 1
           </div>
     
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
            My block 2
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            My block 3
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: It result in three column but I want the same result than my first picture (with bootstrap 3). Should I not use Bootstrap for that ?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't see your picture with bootstrap 3 there is a proxy on my work office do you  have an exemple in another website ?

Comment: Like this but bloc 1 and 2 is my bloc 2 and bloc 3 and 4 is my bloc 3 (and image is my bloc 1)
https://www.google.ch/search?biw=1860&bih=991&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=grid+bootstrap+example&oq=grid+bootstrap+example&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3145.4857.0.4955.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.77hoSjIwqrE#imgdii=0gSLJr77x2whtM:&imgrc=96NJiLoyatlvwM:

Comment: And the image is your block 1 ?

Comment: Yes image is my bloc 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156079/discussion-between-foxcy-and-dessauges-antoine).